# Refining Itertools Product output so that there are equal elements in each list

Tags: python, python-itertools

(Moved to MathOverflow after advice in comments.)

I have two elements, A and B. In a list of length n (n is even, n < 10,000) I am trying to find the number of permutations of A and B in which the numbers of As and Bs are equal.

I have used itertools.product and then looked through the output to find instances where A and B are equal but this gets too slow by n = 30. The first numbers should be 2,6,20,70,252...

Any Python-based solution would be interesting to me, not necessarily using itertools.Product.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That would be ideal, I can't quite figure out the equation though, taking into account that the number of elements need to be equal.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out over there

Comment: MathOverflow is for research-level math. If an undergrad, or a high-schooler, could do it, it's not on topic there. https://math.stackexchange.com/ is the site for the easy stuff.